# Bukkit/Spigot: Removing players from tablist without vanishing them

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am coding a plugin (Spigot v_1.8R3) which creates an individual tablist for every player. To do that, I am using the net.minecraft.server.PacketplayOutPlayerInfo packet. 
So my problem: When I remove all players from the tablist and add just a few (like friends), all players, who are not listed, are invisble.
Is there a solution to clear the tablist without vanishing all players? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: I'm really not sure if this works, but just try after removing the `Player` from TabList `Player.showPlayer(Player2);`.

Comment: No that won't work... He would have to work with Packages... Try to despawn the player and then send a package, that maks a fake player without the given property... Don't know the name anymore

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo pack = new PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo(EnumPlayerInfoAction.REMOVE_PLAYER, EntityPlayer...);
```

Also to convert normal players to there EntityPlayer just use

```
((EntityPlayer)p);
```

Very simple! :D

This will remove any players from anyones list(It's a packet so remember to send it).

> This even works on bungeecord for you bungeecord users(Of course varibles are a bit different)!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am doing now. But the problem is that after I sent this packet, the player won't be rendered by the clients.

Comment: It doesn't remove the player for me. . . Can I see more of your code? do you have an some code you forgot to remove that vanished a player?

Comment: Try to use Player#setTablistName("");